# Help with name of 80s fantasy movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think it was set in the medieval times.

The only scene I can remember was where the hero had a choice to make between two women. One was a REALLY beautiful women, the other was "ugly" and had the face of like a pig or maybe a warthog or something like that. I think she walked around with a hood over her head to hide what she looked like.

The hero ended up choosing the "ugly" women, only to find she didn't really look like that, she was actually the beautiful one and the ugliness was just spell or something. It also turned out that the really hot women was really "ugly" and her beauty was just from a magic spell too (I think)

I think it was some kind of test he had to pass, about true beauty being on the inside.

I'm not sure if it was a Hollywood movie, a made for tv movie, or a tv show.

Can someone please help me out with this?  It's been driving me crazy trying to remember what it was.

Comment: When did you see this? How old was it? What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: It was in the mid 80s around 85 or 86. It was on tv but not sure if it was a Hollywood movie or made for tv. It was English language. Unfortunately that's all I know.

Answer (score 5):

["Merlin and the Sword" (1985)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_and_the_Sword)? Starring Malcolm McDowell. Did the 'ugly' lady look like this?

[image: Pig woman face]

Note: This film was released in some regions as "Arthur the King".

Comment: Hot damn, i think thats it!!!  Thank you so much. You are the only person ive ever talked to that knew it.